# Conditional Aggregation for multiple days of data

Tags: sql, hiveql

I am able to do conditional aggregation for a single day using below SQL but wondering how can I accomplish it within a single query for multiple days. I am trying to do a cartesian product between logs_20190715 and dates but not able to think through further to solve this. Any inputs would be appreciated.

```
--1
    SELECT CAST('2018-11-19' AS TIMESTAMP ) AS time_id,
                   city_id,
                   COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_TRUNC('DAY',logged_at) = CAST( '2018-11-19' AS TIMESTAMP ) THEN user_id END ) AS A,
                   COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN logged_at >= CAST( '2018-11-19' AS TIMESTAMP )  
                                         AND logged_at < CAST( '2018-11-19' AS TIMESTAMP ) + interval '7' DAY 
                                        THEN user_id 
                                    END
                         ) AS B,
                   COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN logged_at < CAST( '2018-11-19' AS TIMESTAMP )  
                                         AND logged_at >= CAST( '2018-11-19' AS TIMESTAMP ) - interval '7' DAY 
                                        THEN user_id 
                                    END
                         ) AS C,
                   COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN logged_at < CAST( '2018-11-19' AS TIMESTAMP )  
                                         AND logged_at >= CAST( '2018-11-19' AS TIMESTAMP ) - interval '28' DAY 
                                        THEN user_id 
                                    END
                         ) AS D,  
                   '2018-11-19' 
              FROM logs_20190715
             WHERE logged_at <= CAST('2018-11-19' AS TIMESTAMP) + interval '10' DAY
               AND logged_at >= CAST('2018-11-19' AS TIMESTAMP) - interval '40' DAY
            GROUP BY 1,2;


--2
SELECT CAST('2018-11-18' AS TIMESTAMP ) AS time_id,
                   city_id,
                   COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE_TRUNC('DAY',logged_at) = CAST( '2018-11-18' AS TIMESTAMP ) THEN user_id END ) AS A,
                   COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN logged_at >= CAST( '2018-11-18' AS TIMESTAMP )  
                                         AND logged_at < CAST( '2018-11-18' AS TIMESTAMP ) + interval '7' DAY 
                                        THEN user_id 
                                    END
                         ) AS B,
                   COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN logged_at < CAST( '2018-11-18' AS TIMESTAMP )  
                                         AND logged_at >= CAST( '2018-11-18' AS TIMESTAMP ) - interval '7' DAY 
                                        THEN user_id 
                                    END
                         ) AS C,
                   COUNT( DISTINCT CASE WHEN logged_at < CAST( '2018-11-18' AS TIMESTAMP )  
                                         AND logged_at >= CAST( '2018-11-18' AS TIMESTAMP ) - interval '28' DAY 
                                        THEN user_id 
                                    END
                         ) AS D,  
                   '2018-11-18' 
              FROM logs_20190715
             WHERE logged_at <= CAST('2018-11-18' AS TIMESTAMP) + interval '10' DAY
               AND logged_at >= CAST('2018-11-18' AS TIMESTAMP) - interval '40' DAY
            GROUP BY 1,2;
```

How can I combine the above two queries into a single query and have the same results produced?( Have date dimension which has all dates in it. )

Comment: Would like to implement the above logic for multiple days and still accomplish the same results.

Comment: How can I do that by joining with date dimension if it's already available...